# Can I pull all of my game center apps and achievements like the Game Center App displays or just current app only

Tags: ios, game-center

Can i view all of my game center achievements within an app I am creating.  Currently I can pull in leaderboard for my apps.  That works fine.  But I need to see all of my scores and achievements for every app I have in game center.  Just like the Game Center app currently does.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It appears to me that this is not a good question for this site, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but in **iTunesConnect** |  | **Features** | **Game Center** there is an option to create "groups" that share achievements and leaderboards across multiple apps. You might be able to achieve what you want by putting all your apps in a single group.